# How to make interactive bullets to my jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I'm trying to make a slider with five pictures and next and previous buttons (they will be styled later). The slider works automatically and when hovering the slider the loop stops as it is supposed to. 
I've tried to add interactive bullets that will respond to its given picture. There should always be one dot highlighted, which is the one corresponding to the currently displayed image.
But I cant get this to work.
Can anyone help ? jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/spwgsqm8/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="quickslider">
<div class="quickslider">
    <img class="slide" id="1" src="Slider_images/gc_slide_1.png" alt="placeholder image">
    <img class="slide" id="2" src="Slider_images/gc_slide_2.png" alt="placeholder image">
    <img class="slide" id="3" src="Slider_images/gc_slide_3.png" alt="placeholder image">
    <img class="slide" id="4" src="Slider_images/gc_slide_4.png" alt="placeholder image">
    <img class="slide" id="5" src="Slider_images/gc_slide_5.png" alt="placeholder image">
</div><!--quickslider-->

<nav class="slider-nav">
    <a href="#1" class="active">1</a>
    <a href="#2" >2</a>
    <a href="#3" >3</a>
    <a href="#4" >4</a>
    <a href="#5" >5</a>
</nav>

<div class="quickslider-nav">
    <a href="#" class="left"onclick="prev(); return false;">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="right" onclick="next(); return false;">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#quickslider{
    width:350px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    position: relative;
    height: 380px;
}

.quickslider{
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    width: 350px; 
    height:350px;
}

.quickslider img{
    display: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    position: absolute;
}

#1 {
    background-image: url(Slider_images/gc_slide_1.png);
}

# 2 {
    background-image: url(Slider_images/gc_slide_2.png);
}

.slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.slider-nav a {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider-nav a.active {
  background: #999;
}
```

**JavaSript**

```
sliderint= 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.quickslider>img#1').fadeIn(300);
    startSlider();
})

function startSlider (){
    count=$(".quickslider>img").size(); 

    loop = setInterval(function(){
        if(sliderNext>count){
            sliderNext=1;
            sliderint=1;
        }

        $('.quickslider>img').fadeOut(300);
        $('.quickslider>img#'+sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

        sliderint=sliderNext;
        sliderNext=sliderNext + 1;
    },5000)
}

function prev(){
    newSlide = sliderint-1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}

function next(){
    newSlide = sliderint+1;
    showSlide(newSlide);   
}

function stopLoop(){
    window.clearInterval(loop);
}

function showSlide(id){
    stopLoop();
    if(id>count){
        id=1;
    }
    else if(id<1){
        id=count;  
    }

    $('.quickslider>img').fadeOut(300);
    $('.quickslider>img#'+id).fadeIn(300);

    sliderint=id;
    sliderNext=id + 1;
    startSlider();   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".quickslider > img").hover(
        function ()
        {
           stopLoop ();
        },
        function () {
            startSlider ();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: So in other word, you're trying to create [a carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Comment: Yes exactly! The slideshow itself works and changes picture every 5 second.

Comment: But the bullets won't work

Comment: Sorry if you find my comment unconstructive, I'm just trying to tell you to use an external library(like slick in my link) to solve your problem. Since carousel is a hard problem on front end that normally take weeks to cover all possible bugs. So why try to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Your comment is in no way unconstructive. I'm just not allowed to use a plug-in or external library. I have to do it from scratch. That's why I'm looking for some help with the bullets.

Comment: add your code on jsfiddle so people can simple edit it, creating basic horizontal slider with previous and next button and bullet is not that hard

Comment: Don't vandalise your question just because you have an answer. Let other people benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2cqnjo/

So since you're only asking about the interactive bullets. I've only focused on them and didn't touch other places.

I added an onclick event handler inside $(document).ready() to detect user click on the bullet, and called showSlide() from there.

```
$('body').on('click', ".slider-nav a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(e.target).attr("href");

    showSlide(href.substring(1, href.length));
  });
```

`showSlide()` has thus become the function to call whenever you want to change slide. Thus I have changed the codes in `startSlider()` a bit to make use of `showSlide()` instead of its current implementation.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I see. The problem is because you were binding the hover event on each img. So when you hover over an img while it was on the process of fading out, eventually it will fade out completely and trigger the hoverout event to start the loop again. Binding the event to the #quickslider itself should solve this. See http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2cqnjo/2/

Comment: Haha wow I learned something new. Apparently when changing slide with bullet the provided id for showSlide() is a string (because the value was cut out from the anchor's href attribute). So later `sliderNext= id + 1` became a string concatenation, in this case becoming 31 instead of 4. Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2cqnjo/4/

Comment: Haha this code is seriously cursed or something ! Everything works when you don't touch anything - once a bullet is pressed one time the hover does not work, but it changes in the right order. When you press one of the bullets a second (or thrid) time it starts jumping around again after a few slides and sometimes speeds up. I really appreciate your huge help !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2cqnjo/8/ urgh this is why I said carousel is not easy >_< Anyway start loop got called twice creating parallel interval. Clearing before setting new fixes it. Also I used setTimeout instead of setInterval now because it's called each time slide change.

Comment: Ah awesome ! I get the problem now. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've created new jquery code base on your HTML output as your old code seems a bit messy. you can modify next function, previous function and bullets functions to animate your display or better animate it with pure CSS like transform, translate or transition, the whole concept is to add `active` class on both bullet and image based on click event. I also modify a bit of your CSS code

you can check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spwgsqm8/8/)

```
(function($){

  $('.nav-thumbs li:first-of-type, .quickslider img:first-of-type').addClass('active');

  //Previous function
  $('.quickslider-nav').on('click', '.left', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showPrevious();
  });
  function showPrevious() {
    if ( !$('.nav-thumbs li:first-of-type').hasClass('active') ) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.nav-thumbs li, .quickslider img').removeClass('active');
      $('.nav-thumbs li:last-of-type, .quickslider img:last-of-type').addClass('active');
    }
  }

  //Next function
  $('.quickslider-nav').on('click', '.right', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showNext();
  });
  function showNext() {
    if ( !$('.nav-thumbs li:last-of-type').hasClass('active') ) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.nav-thumbs li, .quickslider img').removeClass('active');
      $('.nav-thumbs li:first-of-type, .quickslider img:first-of-type').addClass('active');
    }
  }

  // Bullets 
  $('.nav-thumbs').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $('.nav-thumbs li, .quickslider img').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.quickslider img').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
    return false;
  });

  // Autoplay every 3 seconds
  setInterval(function(){
        if( !$('#quickslider').is(':hover') ) {
            showNext();
        }
  }, 3000);
})(jQuery);
```

Forgot the Important part of CSS

this CSS code is necessary to display the image

```
.quickslider img.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I think his original idea of using a centralized showSlide(id) function to change slide is a good approach. OOP and whatnot.

Comment: could be, the code above is just a very basic functionality, for very simple slider, I made it for not more than 15 mins. sure there are countless of better ways to do it.

Comment: Also, HTML 4 can't have an ID that starts with number and it won't work when targeting CSS, though it was accepted on HTML5

Comment: thanks for your help too Silver. Unfortunately I can't get it to work with the correct pictures which is stored on my computer. The slider just shows up blank.

Comment: is there a console log error? inspect the element and check if the first image and first bullet has active class, also, compare your CSS with the CSS on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spwgsqm8/8/) I created

Comment: I edited my answer, forgot to mention your original CSS code doesn't have ```.quickslider img.active {
    display: block;
}``` which needed for displaying the image

Comment: Works now! Thank you so much for your help!
I just have a last question if that's okay - where and how do you define 'li:first-of-type' and  'img:first-of-type '
(I'm quite new to JS and jQuary)

Comment: glad to hear it working, [first-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp) is a CSS3 selector that can also be use in jquery, it will select the first element of the same type inside one parent element, a bit similar to jquery index, same thing for last-of-type though it just for last position, so you can use these psuedo selector instead using a class or ID for selecting an element.

Comment: also, if you worry about older browser support like IE < 9, you can add the same custom class on the first item of your image and first item  of LI bullet, then replace all ```:first-of-type``` with that class you've added, same thing also for ```:last-of-type``` just add a class to the last item of the image and last item of LI bullet then replace ```:last-of-type``` with that class, e.g. ```.quickslider img.last-image``` ```.quickslider img.first-image```

Comment: Ah okay ! Thank you once again !